# php get content image folder svg

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

I'm trying to get the svg files from a folder.

Tried the following ways but none of them seems to work:

```
<?php   
$directory = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myImages/';      
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));
while ($it->valid()) { //Check the file exist
    if (!$it->isDot()) { //if not parent ".." or current "."
        if (strpos($it->key(), '.php') !== false
           || strpos($it->key(), '.css') !== false
           || strpos($it->key(), '.js') !== false
        ) {
        echo $it->key() . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And:

```
global $wp_filesystem;
$path = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myImages/';
$filelist = $wp_filesystem->dirlist( $path );
echo $filelist;
```

And:

```
$path = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myImages/';
$images = scandir( $path, 'svg', $depth = 0);
echo $images;
```

And:

```
$dir    = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myImages/';
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
```

And:

```
$directory = get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/images/myImages/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.svg");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($images);
echo '</pre>';
echo $directory.'abnamro.svg">';
foreach($images as $image)
    {
      echo $image;
    }
```

I'm kinda lost. I might think that there is something else wrong.
Also checked the privileges for the user but all is okay.
I run Wordpress on a local machine with MAMP.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using scandir to get the list of files in the folder and looping through them? http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: Well not looped yet. I tried it and checked the values in an array but the array was empty. Won't get any errors as well

Comment: Is it possible it's looking in the wrong folder? Does get_bloginfo('template_directory') return the right folder?

Comment: Yes it takes the right folder. The first thing I checked ;-)

Comment: So `echo is_dir($directory);` produces `1`?

Comment: Also, your first RecursiveDirectoryIterator example ends up failing, so I don't think that one will return anything except a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Try the function below, I have notated for clarity. Some highlights are:

1. You can skip dots on outset in the directory iterator
2. You can trigger a fatal error if path doesn't exist *(which is the issue in this case, you are using a domain-root path instead of the server root path [`ABSPATH`])*
3. You can choose the extension type to filter files

---

```
function getPathsByKind($path,$ext,$err_type = false)
    {
        # Assign the error type, default is fatal error
        if($err_type === false)
            $err_type   =   E_USER_ERROR;
        # Check if the path is valid
        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            # Throw fatal error if folder doesn't exist
            trigger_error('Folder does not exist. No file paths can be returned.',$err_type);
            # Return false incase user error is just notice...
            return false;
        }
        # Set a storage array
        $file   =   array();
        # Get path list of files
        $it     =   new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
        );
        # Loop and assign paths
        foreach($it as $filename => $val) {
            if(strtolower(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == strtolower($ext)) {
                $file[] =   $filename;
            }
        }
        # Return the path list
        return $file;
    }
```

To use:

```
# Assign directory path
$directory = str_replace('//','/',ABSPATH.'/'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myImages/');
# Get files
$files = getPathsByKind($directory,'svg');
# Check there are files
if(!empty($files)) {
    print_r($files);
}
```

If the path doesn't exist, it will now tell you by way of system error that the path doesn't exist. If it doesn't throw a fatal error and comes up empty, then you actually do have some strange issue going on.

If all goes well, you should get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /data/19/2/133/150/3412/user/12321/htdocs/domain/images/myImages/img1.svg
    [1] => /data/19/2/133/150/3412/user/12321/htdocs/domain/images/myImages/img2.svg
    [2] => /data/19/2/133/150/3412/user/12321/htdocs/domain/images/myImages/img3.svg
    [3] => /data/19/2/133/150/3412/user/12321/htdocs/domain/images/myImages/img4.svg
)
```

If path invalid, will throw:

> **Fatal error:** Folder does not exist. No file paths can be returned. in **/data/19/2/133/150/3412/user/12321/htdocs/domain/index.php** on line **123**

Comment: Thank you for your wel explained answer. It did throw me an error. Saying that the folder doesn't exist. Only problem is that the folder does exist. The permissions are correct... I have tried to use the absolute path, but it keeps giving me the error. Could it be a MAMP/local issue? I'll place it online and see what happens

Comment: Just to be sure..... I added the function to my `functions.php`.... Didn't work though

Comment: I echo'd out the directory and pasted it directly into my browser. It gives me a list of all items within that folder.... I'm lost here.

Comment: It will only list files that have the extension you put into the function as a parameter.

Comment: It says it can't find the folder.

Comment: Then the folder path doesn't exist as you have it. Double-, triple-check the path.

Comment: I quintuple checked it. The path is absolutely correct. If I echo the path and directly load it in my browser it shows the content of the folder. Trust me the folder is there

Comment: `is_dir()` doesn't lie, so the path that `is_dir()` receives is not there, so you may have an absolute/relative path issue.

Comment: Dude..... Tell me I'm wrong. The variable for my path is `$directory` but in the function it tries to call on `$path`. However `$path` is nowhere defined. Oh wait... Never mind... Got it... I'm stupid I know.

Comment: `$path` is in the scope of the function, so it's defined inside the function. The `$directory` is defined outside the scope of the function so when you put `$directory` into the function `$path` takes the place of `$directory` so inside the function it's basically doing `$path = $directory`. You need to see if the path is absolute to your directory. The path you have is relative to your domain root not the server root so it's not finding it. Add `ABSPATH.'/'.` to the front of that path

Comment: Or you can make it relative to the file you are running, but it's better just to have the absolute path, I find.

Comment: Alright, try the update I made to the script. Essentially you are adding the absolute path and removing any double `/`. So: `$directory = str_replace('//','/',ABSPATH.'/'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/myImages/');`

Comment: Okay so the `ABSPATH` gave this as output: `/home/name/subdomain/http:/subdomain.domain.nl/wp-content/themes/themename/images/myImages/` Correct me if I'm wrong but this doesn't seem to be correct... So I changed the `$directory` to something else and this works. However this is merely to understand I would like to have it dynamically: `$directory = str_replace('//','/',ABSPATH.'/wp-content/themes/themename/images/myImages/');` I can't go on and use the absolute path

Comment: Okay so because of the fact that you can't or want to use `ABSPATH` to load images I had to do a `str_replace` looking for the `ABSPATH` and take it out. It works now but I'm not sure if this is the correct/safest way

Comment: `ABSPATH` is just the directory path for the root of the domain. Same as using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (provided that is properly set up on the server), or if you used `__DIR__` in the root. Nothing unsafe about using the absolute path for referencing anything. If you don't sanitize or control what is attached to that path, that's where it's unsafe, but if you don't do that anyway, a relative path will also be unsafe.